# Cannot find source of this Surya Mantra. Can anyone help please?

Tags: identification-request, surya

A very soothing surya mantra was part of Sri Krishna series serial. A show based on 'Shrimad Bhagwat Mahapuran' glorifying Lord Krishna's immortal and eternal life.

Don't know from where this mantra has been taken ? Can someone point me to the right source / book / vedas / purans etc ?

https://youtu.be/DhquMQnBs4s?start=135&end=210